# Large body sent via boost::asio::tcp::ip

Tags: c++, networking, boost, tcp, boost-asio

My protocol is very easy: I sent a `size_t` indicating the size of body and then the body itself.

The code is based on the [official Boost examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), here it is:

```
class tcp_conn : 
        public std::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_conn>, 
        private boost::noncopyable 
    {
    public:
        tcp_conn(ba::io_service& io_service);
        void start();
        void stop();

        tcp::socket& socket();

    private:
        void handle_read_header(const error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
        void handle_read(const error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

        ba::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type buffer_wrapper_;
        ba::streambuf buffer_;
        std::size_t buffer_size_;
        tcp::socket socket_;

};
```

And the implementation is:

```
void tcp_conn::start() {
    socket_.async_read_some(
        ba::buffer(&buffer_size_, sizeof(buffer_size_)),
        boost::bind(
          &tcp_conn::handle_read_header,
          this,
          ba::placeholders::error,
          ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred
          )
        );
}

void tcp_conn::handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
    if(!e) {
        buffer_wrapper_ =  buffer_.prepare(buffer_size_);

        socket_.async_read_some(
            ba::buffer(buffer_wrapper_),
            boost::bind(
              &tcp_conn::handle_read,
              this,
              ba::placeholders::error,
              ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred
              )
            ); 

    } else {
        //stop connection
    }
}


void tcp_conn::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred)   {
    if (!e ) {
        buffer_.commit(bytes_transferred);

        if(buffer_.size() == buffer_size_) {
            std::cout << "WHOLE BODY TRANSFERED NOW" << std::endl;
            //has all data in buffer, handle it.
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "NOT WHOLE BODY TRANSFERED, still got "<< (buffer_size_ - bytes_transferred) << " to go" << std::endl;
            socket_.async_read_some(
                ba::buffer(buffer_wrapper_),
                boost::bind(
                  &tcp_conn::handle_read,
                  this,
                  ba::placeholders::error,
                  ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                  )
                ); 
        }


    }
    else {
        //handle error
    }   
}
```

This doesn't quite work. I'm guessing my error is somewhere in the recursive updates of `buffer_wrapper_` - some data gets lost, overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer_.commit()` invalidates the result of `prepare()`, as documented: ["The returned object is invalidated by any basic_streambuf member function that modifies the input sequence or output sequence."](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/prepare.html)

Actually, instead of preparing buffers manually and chain `async_read_some()`, you can just use the appropriate helper free function with `streambuf` and a completion condition:

```
asio::async_read(
   socket_,
   buffer_, 
   asio::transfer_exactly(buffer_size_),
   boost::bind(&tcp_conn::handle_read, this, _1, _2)
);
```

This way `handle_read` gets invoked when you get the whole message body or an error occures.

Comment: Hey thanks. I was just making it work with a complicated manual buffer updates.. Your answer is almost perfect, but could you supply all namespace prefixes to the above code (where is _1, _2, transfer_exactly etc. defined in?)

Comment: @Queequeg `transfer_exactly` is in `asio` namespace, `_1`, `_2` bind placeholders are in the global namespace (you can keep using the asio placeholders, as in your question).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much cleaner now! And it **does work** :)